# Recursively adding subdict

Tags: python, json, dictionary, recursion

I'm working with some heavily nested dictionaries in Python and am trying to update them recursively. The data (representing an Nary tree) look something like this:

```
{
    "root": {
        "value": 1.0,
        "name": null,
        "children": [
            {
                "value": 0.5,
                "name": null,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "value": 0.5,
                        "name": null,
                        "children": []    
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 3.0,
                        "name": "B",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Every level of the dictionary has a value and name key. **I'd like every instance of these two keys (i.e. at every level) to become the values of an additional subdict** (say, with the name, "text"), i.e. the data need to look like:

```
{
    "root": {
        "text": {
            "value": 1.0,
            "name": null,
        },
        "children": [
            {
                "text": {
                    "value": 0.5,
                    "name": null,
                },
                "children": [
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "value": 0.5,
                            "name": null,
                        },
                        "children": []    
                    },
                    {
                        "text": {
                            "value": 3.0,
                            "name": "B",
                        },
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm sure this is easy to do, but I can't seem to work it out! I've tried a few different approaches using recursion, but I'm running into lots of errors. (If this is easier to do using JSON.parse from javascript, that's also fine.) Any help would be appreciated. The following **extremely wrong** solution was my first stab at this, but it obviously doesn't work as it's incomplete; I'm not sure how one can both access two keys in the same iteration in this recursive manner and update the dict within the same iteration.

```
def add_encapsulation(json_input, lookup_key1, lookup_key2):
    for key, val in json_input.items():
        updated_key = "text"
        subdict = dict()
        if key == lookup_key1:
            vals[key] = json_input["value"]
        elif key == lookup_key2:
            vals[key] = json_input["name"]
            # I can't access the two keys in the same iteration, so you can't add them 
            # to the subdict. Also, how can you add the subdict to the dict at the appropriate place? 
        else:
            add_encapsulation(v, lookup_key1, lookup_key2)
```

Comment: first show your code and full error messages.

Comment: @furas I added my attempt, but it's obviously broken/incomplete –– my specific questions are now noted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The keys under root and then children seem to follow the same pattern(value, name, children) so a recursive function might look like this:

```
data = json.loads('''{
    "root": {
        "value": 1.0,
        "name": null,
        "children": [
            {
                "value": 0.5,
                "name": null,
                "children": [
                    {
                        "value": 0.5,
                        "name": null,
                        "children": []    
                    },
                    {
                        "value": 3.0,
                        "name": "B",
                        "children": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}''')


def encapsulate(d):
    rv = {}
    value, name, children = d.values()
    rv['text'] = {'value': value, 'name': name}
    rv['children'] = [encapsulate(c) for c in children]

    return rv


print({'root': encapsulate(data['root'])})
```

Output:

```
{'root': {'text': {'value': 1.0, 'name': None}, 'children': [{'text': {'value': 0.5, 'name': None}, 'children': [{'text': {'value': 0.5, 'name': None}, 'children': []}, {'text': {'value': 3.0, 'name': 'B'}, 'children': []}]}]}}
```